# Positioning labels/inputs together in an inline-block format

Tags: html, css, position

I am having an issue positioning two of my labels/inputs to make them inline, but also appear in a block format. I have tried changing `account-input-med` to `display: inline`, `display: inline-block`, but it always makes the labels appear inline.

Does anyone see what I need to do to get my state/zip label/inputs to appear like the image below?

[image]

```css
.right-container {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.account-label {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
.account-input, .account-input-med, .account-input-large {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin: 15px 0;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    color: #5E5E5E;
}
.account-input {
    width: 80%;
}
.account-input-med {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.account-input-large {
    width: 40%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-container">
  <!-- Right Address Container -->
  <h2 class="account-section-subtitle lato">Shipping Address</h2>
  <label class="account-label">City</label>
  <input type="text" class="account-input">
  <label class="account-label">State</label>
  <input type="text" class="account-input-med">
  <label class="account-label">Zip/Postal Code</label>
  <input type="text" class="account-input-med">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the inputs in the label:

```
  <label class="account-label">
    <span>State</span>
    <input type="text" class="account-input">
  </label>
```

Css:

```
.account-label {
  display: inline-block;
}
.account-input {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Place a

```
    <br/>
```

after the label to make the input start on a new line.

e.g.

```
      <label class="account-label">City</label>&nbsp
      <label class="account-label">State</label><br/>
      <input type="text" class="account-input">&nbsp
      <input type="text" class="account-input-med">
```

Comment: I'm looking for a css method. Thanks though.

Comment: You could use a table element to place the input boxes side by side
<table><tr><td>[label]<br/>[input]</td><td>[label]<br/>[input]</td></tr></table> for example.